# Webpack as simple webserver

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

How can I use Webpack or Webpack-dev-server as most simple static webserver?

No build, no watch, no nothing, just deliver the files from a specified directory?

Something like:

```
webpack serve --port 8010 --static ./some-folder
```